# Recursively list hidden files without ls, find or extendedglob

Tags: bash, recursion, hidden-files, built-in

As an exercise I have set myself the task of recursively listing files using bash builtins. I particularly don't want to use ls or find and I would prefer not to use setopt extendedglob. The following appears to work but I cannot see how to extend it with /.* to list hidden files. Is there a simple workaround?

```
g() { for k in "$1"/*; do # loop through directory
[[ -f "$k" ]] && { echo "$k"; continue; }; # echo file path
[[ -d "$k" ]] && { [[ -L "$k" ]] && { echo "$k"; continue; }; # echo symlinks but don't follow
g "$k"; }; # start over with new directory
done; }; g "/Users/neville/Desktop" # original directory
```

Added later: sorry - I should have said: 'bash-3.2 on OS X'

Comment: Starting in `bash` 4.1, you can use extended patterns in the argument to `==` and `!=` without explicitly turning on `extglob`, if that's your objection.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for k in "$1"/*; do
```

to

```
for k in "$1"/* "$1"/.[^.]* "$1"/..?*; do
```

The second glob matches all files whose names start with a dot followed by anything other than a dot, while the third matches all files whose names start with two dots followed by something. Between the two of them, they will match all hidden files other than the entries `.` and `..`.

Unfortunately, unless the shell option `nullglob` is set, those (like the first glob) could remain as-is if there are no files whose names match (extremely likely in the case of the third one) so it is necessary to verify that the name is actually a file.

An alternative would be to use the much simpler glob `"$1"/.*`, which will always match the `.` and `..` directory entries, and will consequently always be substituted. In that case, it's necessary to remove the two entries from the list:

```
for k in "$1"/* "$1"/.*; do
  if ! [[ $k =~ /\.\.?$ ]]; then
    # ...
  fi
done
```

(It is still possible for `"$1"/*` to remain in the list, though. So that doesn't help as much as it might.)

Comment: I actually like this answer better than mine (and this is how I would personally do it) because it works in shells other than Bash.  But since the OP did say "bash" specifically, I went ahead and contributed the GLOBIGNORE solution, which automagically skips `.` and `..`. :)

Comment: Both of these work well and I can see what they are doing but I don't understand why. Without them use of "$1"/.* slowly produces many directories: /Users/neville/Desktop/test dir/././././././././././. - Why is this? Is the dot file acting like a symlink to a directory and if so why is it not stopped by my symlink trap? If I was happy to list all the UNIX dot and double dot files how should it be modified?

Answer (score 1):

Set the GLOBIGNORE file to exclude `.` and `..`, which implicitly turns on "shopt -u dotglob".  Then your original code works with no other changes.

```
user@host [/home/user/dir]
$ touch file
user@host [/home/user/dir]
$ touch .dotfile
user@host [/home/user/dir]
$ echo *
file
user@host [/home/user/dir]
$ GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
user@host [/home/user/dir]
$ echo *
.dotfile file
```

Note that this is bash-specific.  In particular, it does not work in ksh.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple arguments to `for`:

```bash
for k in "$1"/* "$1"/.*; do
```

But if you do search for `.*` in directories , you should be aware that it also gives you the `.` and `..` files. You may also be given a nonexistent file if the `"$1"/*` glob matches, so I would check that too.

With that in mind, this is how I would correct the loop:

```bash
g() {
    local k subdir
    for k in "$1"/* "$1"/.*; do # loop through directory
        [[ -e "$k" ]] || continue  # Skip missing files (unmatched globs)
        subdir=${k##*/}
        [[ "$subdir" = . ]] || [[ "$subdir" = .. ]] && continue  # Skip the pseudo-directories "." and ".."

        if [[ -f "$k" ]] || [[ -L "$k" ]]; then
            printf %s\\n "$k"  # Echo the paths of files and symlinks
        elif [[ -d "$k" ]]; then
            g "$k"  # start over with new directory
        fi
    done
}
g ~neville/Desktop
```

Here the funky-looking `${k##*/}` is just a fast way to take the basename of the file, while `local` was put in so that the variables don't modify any existing variables in the shell.

One more thing I've changed is `echo "$k"` to `printf %s\\n "$k"`, because `echo` is irredeemably flawed in its argument handling and should be avoided for the purpose of echoing an unknown variable. (See [Rich's sh tricks](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html) for an explanation of how; it boils down to -n and -e throwing a spanner in the works.)

By the way, this will NOT print sockets or fifos - is that intentional?